# Union with null columns or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to union two tables columns, where one table colum is null or not. And another table column has value.
How to do that?

Table 1

```
uid | name  | up | uc
----|-------|----|----
 1  | test1 | 12 | 12
 2  | test2 | 23 | 34
 3  | test3 | 43 | 33
```

Table 2

```
id  | uid | points
----|-----|----------
1   |  1  |   45
2   |  2  |   23
```

Now i want to union uid 3. I tried but failed everytimes.

Comment: explain better please. What is the output

Comment: show us the code u did so far

Answer (score 1):

Use left join: using left join you get all rows from left table and in this case union is not required

```
select datatable1.*, points
from datatable1 left join datatable2
on datatable1.uid=datatable2.uid
```